# change jupyter notebook theme to default

Tags: jupyter-notebook, themes

I used jupyterthemes library to change my notebook theme but after I delete anaconda for something I see I cant change my notebook theme to default because

```
jt -r
```

and

```
!jt -r
```

and

```
! jt -r
```

doesn't work, and I receive this error :

```
'jt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

or this error:

```
'!' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

or this error:

```
'!jt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How to resolve this?